# how i can search multiple word search in Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

***> here is the code***.

> **i want to search the every word in my database but the results only show with single keyword not the multiple.** 
>   it is a PDO database
>   when i search single word like ***facebook*** then the result is appear
>   if i search two or more word search then the result is not appear.

'

```
function getResults(){
 $q=$GLOBALS['q'];
 $p=$GLOBALS['p'];
 $start=($p-1)*10;
 if($p!=null){
  $starttime = microtime(true);
  $sql=$GLOBALS['dbh']->prepare('SELECT title, url, description FROM search WHERE `title` LIKE :q OR `url` LIKE :q OR `description` LIKE :q ');
  $sql->bindValue(":q", "%$q%");
  $sql->execute();
  $trs=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $endtime = microtime(true);
  if($sql->rowCount()==0 || $start>$sql->rowCount()){
   return 0;
  }else{
   $duration = $endtime - $starttime;
   $res=array();
   $res['count']=$sql->rowCount();
   $res['time']=round($duration, 4);
   $limitedResults=array_slice($trs, $start, 12);
   foreach($limitedResults as $r){
    $res["results"][]=array($r['title'], $r['url'], $r['description']);
   }
   return $res;
  }
 }
}
?>
```

'

Comment: How do you pass multiple words? In 1 variable?

Comment: did you mean i add another variable..?

Comment: do you want your search to search for facebook and linked within the fields? and if so how do you want to pass them to your query

Comment: i didn't understand what you told

Comment: i want to make a PDO query that the result with multiple query

Comment: like in the browser URL field like this .com/search?/google+facebook+yahoo etc and the given  output is null

Comment: @Altamash    daviestrachan@yahoo.co.uk

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is complete script you found helpful.

```
 <?php  
                 if(isset($_GET["search"]))  
                 {  
                      $condition = '';  
                      //$query = explode(" ", $_GET["search"]);
                      $query = explode(" ", $_GET["search"]);

                      foreach($query as $text)  
                      {  
                           $condition .= "`title`  LIKE +'%".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $text)."%' OR ";  
                      }  
                      $condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);  
                      $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM countries2 WHERE " . $condition;  
                      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql_query);  
                      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
                      {  
                           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                           {  
                                echo '<tr><td>'.$row["title"].'</td></tr>';  
                           }  
                      }  
                      else  
                      {  
                           echo '<label>Data not Found</label>';  
                      }  
                 }  
                 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you didn't use @david strachan 's approach (which I think is a very good solution), but I will try to explain an option you might also use and understand why you're not getting any result currently.

At this point what happens is, you're sending these values to your query which eventually becomes;

```
SELECT title, url, description FROM search WHERE `title` LIKE `google+facebook+yahoo` OR `url` LIKE `google+facebook+yahoo` OR `description` LIKE `google+facebook+yahoo`
```

I don't think you want to look for a tittle containing all of these.

I'm not sure how to write this using a query but a quick solution for you could be like this.

1. Insert the values into an array (google+facebook+yahoo)
2. use a loop to select each key from the array created and pass that to the query
3. make the query **add** it's result as an array

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build a dynamic query to search for two words. In the code below I illustrate building query using GET for showing query and array. I use unnamed parameters `?` and "lazy" binding when possible - passing data into execute for ease.

```
//Using GET here for testing

<?php
//Using GET here for testing
if(isset($_GET['q'])){
$q = $_GET['q'];
//}
//First split string
if (strpos($q, ' ') > 0) {
$pieces = explode(" ", $q);
//echo count($pieces);  
//You need an array to store columns
$columnArray = array( "title", "url", "description");
//You need an array to store parameters
$paramArray =array();
$clause = "WHERE";
}
//You need to build a dynamic query to perform this. Start with a basic stub

    $sql = "SELECT `title`, `url`, `description` FROM search ";

//Start building the query
//Also see PDO WIKI for use % in placeholders.ie placeholders cannot represent an arbitrary part of the query, but a complete data literal only
//Loop through columns
        foreach ($columnArray  as $column) {
            //$sql .
            foreach ($pieces as $value) {
                $sql .= " $clause $column LIKE ?";
            $clause = "OR";
            array_push($paramArray,"%$value%");
            }
} 

//echo query and parameter array
echo $sql;
echo "<br>";  
print_r($paramArray);

//Prepare and execute query 
//  $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
//  $sth->execute($paramArray);
}
?>
```

Result from
xxx.php?q=google amazon quora
or xxx.php?q=google+amazon+quora

```
    SELECT `title`, `url`, `description` FROM search WHERE title LIKE ? OR title LIKE ? OR title LIKE ? OR url LIKE ? OR url LIKE ? OR url LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?
Array ( [0] => %google% [1] => %amazon% [2] => %quora% [3] => %google% [4] => %amazon% [5] => %quora% [6] => %google% [7] => %amazon% [8] => %quora% )
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer but the output is following error in browser.                                                                                         SELECT title, url, description FROM search WHERE `title` LIKE google OR `url` LIKE google
Array ( [0] => %google% [1] => %google% )

Comment: and i also using PDO for result basically you can say this a some kind of little search engine and im using MYISAM database?

Comment: Did you try the code given? You seemed to have modified **WHERE `title` LIKE ?**.You must retain **?**

Comment: ouput is the following error:   Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: here is the 1st part of my script

Comment: dear david i cant edit my above post can u give me your email id then i will send you my both script maybe that is helpful for my please.